# UICollectionView Drag and Drop cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

Hi I want to do drag drop using uicollectionview. When performing drag and drop it is moving contents i want to do it like in the photo. I want the box to carry itself. For example; when I drag the photo to 4  I should leave the red area with full measurements. Swap photo 6 to photo 1 like taking photo 3 to the left. I have researched in uicollectionview so much but I can’t find anything like this.   Please help me

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 var cellIds = ["image 1","image 2","image 3","image 4","image 5","6","7"]
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 10)

    let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                         action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer:)))
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let view = gestureRecognizer.view else { return }
    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location) else { break }
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(location)
    case .ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
   }
  }



extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource,
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellIds.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SampleCell", for: indexPath) as! SampleCell

    let text = cellIds[indexPath.item]
    cell.label.text = text

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let text = cellIds.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    cellIds.insert(text, at: destinationIndexPath.item)

    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {
            return CGSize(width: 190, height: 100)
        }

        if (indexPath.row==1)
        {
            return CGSize(width: 190, height: 100)
        }

        if (indexPath.row==2)
        {
            return CGSize(width: 190, height: 400)
        }

        if (indexPath.row==3)
         {
             return CGSize(width: 400, height: 200)
         }
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
}


}

final class SampleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()



    let size = self.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)

    var newFrame = layoutAttributes.frame
    // note: don't change the width
    newFrame.size.height = ceil(size.height)

    layoutAttributes.frame = newFrame

    return layoutAttributes
}
}
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMrUG.png)

Comment: I think this is not possible to accomplish using just 1 collection view. This might be needing a complex setup of a couple of collectionViews near to each other, and then handle the drag & drop between collectionViews. My suggestion: come up with a simpler design, otherwise this will be a very sophisticated approach to handle.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UICollectionViewDragDelegate`,

For multiple sections, in order to drag to the end item, we should add an extra item when dragging.

[image: img]

**Sample Code:**

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

enum CellModel {
    case simple(text: String)
    case availableToDropAtEnd
}

class SecondController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"
    private lazy var supplementaryViewIdentifier = "supplementaryViewIdentifier"
    private lazy var sections = 10
    private lazy var itemsInSection = 2
    private lazy var numberOfElementsInRow = 3

    private lazy var data: [[CellModel]] = {
        var count = 0
        return (0 ..< sections).map { _ in
            return (0 ..< itemsInSection).map { _ -> CellModel in
                count += 1
                return .simple(text: "cell \(count)")
            }
        }
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        let _numberOfElementsInRow = CGFloat(numberOfElementsInRow)
        let allWidthBetwenCells = _numberOfElementsInRow == 0 ? 0 : collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing*(_numberOfElementsInRow-1)
        let width = (view.frame.width - allWidthBetwenCells)/_numberOfElementsInRow
        collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        collectionViewFlowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 40)

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(SupplementaryView.self,
                                forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                withReuseIdentifier: supplementaryViewIdentifier)

        collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        collectionView.reorderingCadence = .fast
        collectionView.dropDelegate = self
        collectionView.dragDelegate = self

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}



extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDelegate { }


extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        switch data[indexPath.section][indexPath.item] {
            case .simple(let text):
                cell.label?.text = text
                cell.backgroundColor = .gray
            case .availableToDropAtEnd:
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: supplementaryViewIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    }
}




extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDragDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "\(indexPath)" as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return [dragItem]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForAddingTo session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "\(indexPath)" as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return [dragItem]
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragSessionWillBegin session: UIDragSession) {
        var itemsToInsert = [IndexPath]()
        (0 ..< data.count).forEach {
            itemsToInsert.append(IndexPath(item: data[$0].count, section: $0))
            data[$0].append(.availableToDropAtEnd)
        }
        collectionView.insertItems(at: itemsToInsert)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragSessionDidEnd session: UIDragSession) {
        var removeItems = [IndexPath]()
        for section in 0..<data.count {
            for item in  0..<data[section].count {
                switch data[section][item] {
                    case .availableToDropAtEnd:
                        removeItems.append(IndexPath(item: item, section: section))
                    case .simple:
                        break
                }
            }
        }
        removeItems.forEach { data[$0.section].remove(at: $0.item) }
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: removeItems)
    }
    
    
}




extension SecondController: UICollectionViewDropDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        } else {
            // useless, just in case
            let section = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
            let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
            destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        }

        switch coordinator.proposal.operation {
            case .move:
                reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath:destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
            default:
                break
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        // made the above logic useless
        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag, destinationIndexPath != nil {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
        else {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
        }
    }

    
    
    private
    func reorderItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        let items = coordinator.items
        if items.count == 1, let item = items.first,
            let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath,
            let localObject = item.dragItem.localObject as? CellModel {

            collectionView.performBatchUpdates ({
                data[sourceIndexPath.section].remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
                data[destinationIndexPath.section].insert(localObject, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
                collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sourceIndexPath])
                collectionView.insertItems(at: [destinationIndexPath])
            })
        }
    }

   
}
```

View:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var label: UILabel?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        clipsToBounds = true
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        self.label = label
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        label?.text = nil
        backgroundColor = .white
    }
}



class SupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
      override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
      }

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      }
}
```

### [github link](https://github.com/coyingcat/CardCollection)

Comment: Hi, I have array of dictionary. Will i able to do this with that array? I know how to drag array of string. but I am not familiar with this. can you help me

Comment: sure.  download every sample code,  run & learn